# Transforming arbitrary distributions to distributions on $[0,1]$

Tags: distributions

I was reading Robert Serfling's 1980 book "Approximation Theorems of Mathematical Statistics" and came across the following construction of the Dvoretzky–Kiefer–Wolfowitz inequality for arbitrary distributions $F$,  which DKW prove for distributions on $[0,1]$.

> Given independent $X_i$ with d.f. F and defined on a common probability space, one can construct independent uniform $[0,1]$ variates $Y_i$ such that $\mathbf{P}[X_i = F^{-1}(Y_i)] =1,\forall i$.

Why? Is this true for arbitrary distributions (including discontinuous ones)?

Secondly,

> Let $G$ denote the uniform $[0,1]$ distribution and $G_n$ the sample distribution function of the $Y_i$s. Then $F(x)=G(F(x))$ and with probability $1$, $F_n(x) = G_n(F(x))$.

Why?

Now I don't understand quantile functions as well I would like, and so am having some trouble following these arguments.

Edit: All of this is on page 59 of the book.

---

whuber, thank you so much for your careful answer. It is appreciated. The answer to my question does indeed lie in the last paragraph of your reply - now if I could only wrap my head around it.

What is throwing me off is the following example which I have recreated from Galen Shorack's "Probability for Statisticians" (page 111). Here, the Lebesgue measure of the set $[X\neq F^{-1}Y]$ is not zero. Would you agree? I am referring to the points in the interval $(2,3)$ and in $(3,3.5)$ for which the inverse transformation does not bring any points back.
Thank you again for looking into this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
% Graphics
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}

% An arbitrary CDF
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{psgraph}[arrows=<->](0,0)(-1.5,-.3)(6,1.2){.5\textwidth}{2.5cm}
 \psplot[algebraic, linecolor=black]{-1}{1}{.025*x^2+.1*x+.175} % {this goes from .1 --> .3}
 \psplot[algebraic, linecolor=black]{1}{2}{-.1*x^2+.4*x+.1}  % {this goes form .4 --> .5}
 \psline[linecolor=black](2,.5)(3,.5)  % this stays at .5
 \psline[linecolor=black](3,.6)(3.5,.6)  % this stays at .6
 \psplot[algebraic, linecolor=black]{3.5}{5}{  -0.1333*(x-5)^2+.9}  % this goes from .6 --> .9
 \psdots[dotstyle=*](3,.6)(1,0.4)
  \end{psgraph}
\end{center}
\caption{Arbitrary CDF with discontinuities and flat sections}
\label{fig:cdf}
\end{figure}

% The quantile function
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{psgraph}[arrows=<->](0,0)(-.3, -1.5)(1.2, 6){2cm}{5cm}
% inverses using the Matlab finverse symbolic toolbox function
\psplot[algebraic, linecolor=black]{.1}{.3}{20*(x/10 - 3/400)^(1/2) - 2} 
\psline[linecolor=black](.3, 1)(.4, 1)  
\psplot[algebraic, linecolor=black]{.4}{.5}{-((x-0.5)/(-0.1))^(0.5)+2}  
\psline[linecolor=black](.5, 3)(.6, 3)
\psplot[algebraic, linecolor=black]{.6}{.9}{-((x-.9)/(-0.1333))^(0.5)+5}
\psdots[dotstyle=*](.6, 3)(.5, 2)
\end{psgraph}
\end{center}
\caption{Quantile function of CDF in figure (\protect \ref{fig:cdf})}
\label{fig:qf}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

PS. I could not use the comment box for the reply as I needed to use the `<code`> environment.

Comment: Re the edit: The Lebesgue measure of this set is irrelevant. You need to be looking at the probability that the CDF of a uniform distribution on Y does not agree with the CDF of X. This probability is still zero. Take a closer look at the Web page I referenced and think harder about the Bernoulli case: once you understand this (the simplest possible situation) all should be clear. (This comment was originally posted Dec 19 '10.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s much easier to simultaneously construct $X_i$ and $Y_i$ having the desired properties,
by first letting $Y_i$ be i.i.d. Uniform$[0,1]$ and then taking $X_i = F^{-1}(Y_i)$.  This is the basic method for generating random variables with arbitrary distributions.
The other direction, where you are first given $X_i$ and then asked to construct $Y_i$, is more difficult, but is still possible for all distributions.  You just have to be careful with how you define $Y_i$.

Attempting to define $Y_i$ as $Y_i = F(X_i)$ fails to produce uniformly distributed $Y_i$ when $F$ has jump discontinuities.  You have to spread the point masses in the distribution of $X_i$ across the the gaps created by the jumps.

Let $$D = \{x : F(x) \neq \lim_{z \to x^-} F(z)\}$$ denote the set of jump discontinuities of $F$.  ($\lim_{z\to x^-}$ denotes the limit from the left.  All distributions functions are right continuous, so the main issue is left discontinuities.)

Let $U_i$ be i.i.d. Uniform$[0,1]$ random variables, and define
$$Y_i = 
\begin{cases}
F(X_i), & \text{if }X_i \notin D \\
U_i F(X_i) + (1-U_i) \lim_{z \to X_i^-} F(z), & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
The second part of the definition fills in the gaps uniformly.

The quantile function $F^{-1}$ is not a genuine inverse when $F$ is not 1-to-1. Note that if $X_i \in D$ then $F^{-1}(Y_i) = X_i$, because the pre-image of the gap is the corresponding point of discontinuity.  For the continuous parts where $X_i \notin D$, the flat sections of $F$ correspond to intervals where $X_i$ has 0 probability so they don’t really matter when considering $F^{-1}(Y_i)$.

The second part of your question follows from similar reasoning after the first part which asserts that $X_i = F^{-1}(Y_i)$ with probability 1.  The empirical CDFs are defined as

$$G_n(y) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{\{Y_i \leq y\}}$$
$$F_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{\{X_i \leq x\}}$$

so

$$
\begin{align}
G_n(F(x)) 
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{\{Y_i \leq F(x) \}} 
= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{\{F^{-1}(Y_i) \leq x \}} 
= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{\{X_i \leq x \}} 
= F_n(x)
\end{align}
$$
with probability 1.

It should be easy to convince yourself that $Y_i$ has Uniform$[0,1]$ distribution by looking at pictures.  Doing so rigorously is tedious, but can be done.  We have to verify that $P(Y_i \leq u) = u$ for all $u \in (0,1)$.  Fix such $u$ and let $x^* = \inf\{x : F(x) \geq u \}$ — this is just the value of quantile function at $u$.  It’s defined this way to deal with flat sections.  We’ll consider two separate cases.

First suppose that $F(x^*) = u$.  Then 
$$
Y_i \leq u
\iff Y_i \leq F(x^*)
\iff F(X_i) \leq F(x^*).
$$
Since $F$ is a non-decreasing function and $F(x^*) = u$,
$$
F(X_i) \leq F(x^*) \iff X_i \leq x^* .
$$
Thus, 
$$
P[Y_i \leq u]
= P[X_i \leq x^*]
= F(x^*)
= u .
$$

Now suppose that $F(x^*) \neq u$.  Then necessarily $F(x^*) > u$, and $u$ falls inside one of the gaps.  Moreover, $x^* \in D$, because otherwise $F(x^*) = u$ and we have a contradiction.
Let $u^* = F(x^*)$ be the upper part of the gap.  Then by the previous case, 
$$
\begin{align}
P[Y_i \leq u]
&= P[Y_i \leq u^*] - P[u < Y_i \leq u^*]\\
&= u^* - P[u < Y_i \leq u^*].
\end{align}
$$
By the way $Y_i$ is defined,  $P(Y_i = u^*) = 0$ and 
$$
\begin{align}
P[u < Y_i \leq u^*] 
&= P[u < Y_i < u^*] \\
&= P[u < Y_i < u^* , X_i = x^*] \\
&= u^* - u .
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $P[Y_i \leq u] = u$.

Comment: "For the continuous parts where Xi∉D, the flat sections of F correspond to intervals where Xi has 0 probability so they don’t really matter when considering F−1(Yi)."
That is it! That was a beautiful answer. Thank you.

Comment: +1 for the rigor and for addressing the second question about the EDFs.

Answer (score 14):

This is merely saying that $F(x) = \Pr[X \le x] = \Pr[F(X) \le F(x)]$ which is exactly what it means for $F(X)$ to have a uniform distribution.

OK, let's go a little slower.

For continuous distributions, forget for a moment that the CDF $F$ is a CDF and think of it as just a nonlinear way to re-express the values of $X$.  In fact, to make the distinction clear, suppose that $G$ is *any* monotonically increasing way of re-expressing $X$.  Let $Y$ be the name of its re-expressed value.  $G^{-1}$, by definition, is the "back transform": it expresses $Y$ back in terms of the original $X$.

What is the distribution of $Y$?  As always, we discover this by picking an arbitrary value that $Y$ might take on, say $y$, and ask for the chance that $Y$ is less than or equal to $y$.  Back-transform this question in terms of the original way of expressing $X$: we are inquiring about the chance that $X$ is less than or equal to $x = G^{-1}(y)$.  Now take $G$ to be $F$ and remember that $F$ is the CDF of $X$: by definition, the chance that $X$ is less than or equal to any $x$ is $F(x)$.  In this case,

$$F(x) = F(G^{-1}(y)) = F(F^{-1}(y)) = y.$$

We have established that the CDF of $Y$ is $\Pr[Y \le y] = y$, the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.

It can help to look at this graphically.  Draw the graph of $F$.  As $X$ ranges over the reals, $F$ ranges between $0$ and $1$.  The function $F$ is constructed *specifically* so that the distribution of $F(x)$ is uniform.  That is, if you want to pick a random value for $X$, pick a *uniformly* random value along the y-axis between $0$ and $1$ and find the value of $X$ where $F(X)$ equals that random height.

In the continuous case we have $X = F^{-1}(Y)$ so clearly $\Pr[X = F^{-1}(Y)] = 1$.  In the discontinuous case there's no difficulty, either, provided we define $F^{-1}$ appropriately.  But if there's a jump in $X$ from $x_0$ to $x_1 \gt x_0$, all we can say in general is that the event where $x_0 \le X \lt x_1$ has zero probability, not that it's impossible for $X$ to lie in this interval.  For this reason we cannot assert that $X = F^{-1}(Y)$ everywhere, but we can assert that the event that this equality does not hold has probability zero, because it consists of at most a countable number of jumps.

(For a practical example of why this arcane technical distinction is important, consider a gambling problem.  Suppose you will play Roulette repeatedly with a fixed bet until either you are broke or you double your money.  Let $X$ be the random variable representing your net gain *if you ever go broke or double your money*.  Otherwise, define $X$ to be any number you want.  $X$ has a Bernoulli distribution because there is some chance $p$ you will go broke, the chance of doubling your money is $1-p$ (work it out!), and the chance of playing forever is zero.  Nevertheless, playing forever is a possibility: it is part of the mathematical set of possible outcomes.)

As a simple exercise in learning to reason with the uniform probability transform, graph $F$ for a Bernoulli($p$) variable.  The graph equals $0$ for all $x \lt 0$, jumps to $1-p$ at $0$, is horizontal again for $0 \lt x \lt 1$, then jumps to $1$ at $x=1$ and stays there for all greater $x$.  A uniform variate on the interval $[0,1]$ on the y-axis will cover the initial jump with a probability $p$; $F^{-1}$ maps this down to $x = 0$.  Otherwise, the variate covers the final jump with the remaining probability $1-p$ and $F^{-1}$ maps this down to $1$.  We see, then, how a uniform distribution of $Y$ reproduces this simple discrete distribution function.  Illustrations of CDFs of discrete and continuous/discrete distributions appear on [this page](http://www.quantdec.com/envstats/notes/class_05/distributions.htm) I wrote for a stats course long ago.